# Can I collect data from form fields with Google Analytics?

Tags: forms, google-analytics

I have a website with a "contact me" form. Users can leave their name, email, and message and I'll get an email containing their data.

I've set up a goal on Google Analytics for the registration and everything works fine.

Now, the question is: Can I see their names and emails on my Analytics? Is there any way to make Google Analytics save that data and show it to me?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: This is a poor use of Google Analytics - it won't help you measure or improve the traffic to your website.

If you are trying to store names and emails from a contact form, and **don't** have a database, you should consider setting up a simple Google Spreadsheets form: http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=87809

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically this can be done using custom variables. See: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

However, I believe that name and email address are considered Personally Identifiable Information so sending it to Google Analytics is most likely against their Terms of Service. See section 7: http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/tos.html

You would need to use another tracking system such as Piwik: http://piwik.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using event tracking.

eg.

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Registration', 'FirstName', $('FirstName').val()]);">Register</a>
```